# Django view is not loading changes

Tags: python, django, postgresql, nginx

I am a django beginner. I have a deployed django app with nginx, uwSGI and postgresql. When I try to change some code in a view, this one is reflected in the client side but the error continues existing, thanks.

**Here is the output failure:**

```
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: NameError
Exception Value:    
global name 'buffer_desc' is not defined
Exception Location: ./vitrasa/views.py in change_priority, line 140
Python Executable:  /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
```

**Here is the code:**

```
def change_priority(id_zone):
        zone_pet=Zone.objects.filter(id=id_zone)
        buffer_desc = 0
        buffer_actv = 0
        for i in zone_pet:
                if i.vitrasa_pet == True & i.esycsa_pet == True:
                        buffer_actv=struct.pack("!7i",2,5,5,int(float(i.zone_regulator)),int(float(i.zone_detector)),1,3)
                        buffer_desc=struct.pack("!9i",2,5,0,5,0,int(float(i.zone_regulator)),int(float(i.zone_detector)),0,3)
                        Zone.objects.filter(id=id_zone).update(pet_state=True,expire_pet=expire_hour())
                        #riteLog("System","ACTV",i.zone_name,"")
                        t = data_send(i.id , i.zone_ip , buffer_actv , buffer_desc)
                        t.start()
                else:
                        Zone.objects.filter(id=id_zone).update(pet_state=False, expire_pet="")
                        #riteLog("System","DESC",i.zone_name,"")
```

As you can see, the name of the variable is already defined

Comment: Is the function where the error is, thanks

Comment: You are missing closing parenthesis in two lines after if statement

Comment: oh my god thanks, but the error variable buffer_desc is not defined continues

Comment: is it solved or you are still getting some error?

Comment: the same error continues

Comment: @Andoni make sure your indent is correct!

Comment: Also if you change your code directly in production server make sure to restart everything properly so changes can actually apply

Comment: After updating the changes you need to start your uwsgi server again then it will reflect your changes.

Comment: No need to restart your nginx if your going to use same port and ip for uwsgi as you have used before.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking on restart uwsgi, thanks, I will try now

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, the problem was that, you have to restart uwsgi process to apply changes in the project